# CakePHP 1.3: how to execute an action without going to its view

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a page via the action `search` where a user can specify some options to bring up rows of data. This process take a few seconds because there is quite a bit of back-end logic required. On the returned data, the user has the ability to add a row of data to another table via the action `add_data` for future reference.

Note that the search result data is saved in a table in order for me to have the row readily available if the user decides to save it (the search result is a compilation of data from multiple databases). After the action `add_data`, I want to be able to maintain the `search` view with the search result instead of letting the browser go to the `add_data` view and go back to the referrer, where there will be no search result.

Now, I know I can check for this table where I save the search result and just have that loaded on the `search` view, but I'm interested in knowing if it's possible to run  another action while keeping the current action view intact without consulting the database. As far as I know, no kind of `$this->redirect(...)` works because the search result page's URL lacks any arguments (e.g. `mycontroller/search`).

I added a button that adds the user-desired data using the following code:

```
echo $this->Html->link('+', array('action' => 'add_data', $reference_id));    // + button is created
```

Is there a way to do this? Preferably using minimal Javascript.

Comment: I can think of two options; either via an AJAX request with JavaScript, or open the link in a new browser window by setting the 'target' to '_blank', i.e. `echo $this->Html->link('+', array('action' => 'add_data', $reference_id), array('target' => '_blank'));`

Comment: Yes, I think ajax is your friend here.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the steps [here](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Helpers/AJAX.html) to add ajax support to your cake project.

Then, enable the ajax helper in the controller that renders your search view:

```
$this->helpers('Ajax');
```

You should be able to render your link like this and it will not direct the user away from the search page:

```
<?php echo $this->Ajax->link(
  '+', 
  array('action' => 'add_data', $reference_id),
  array('update' => 'my-div')
); 
?>
<div id='my-div'></div>
```

Since you want the user to be able to send data to that action, you may want to look into posting a form instead of just a link.  The Ajax helper also provides that ability to submit a form via Ajax:

```
echo $form->create();
echo $form->input('field1');
echo $form->input('field2');
echo $ajax->submit('Submit', array(
   'url'=> array('controller'=>'mycontroller', 'action'=>'add_data'),
   'update' => 'my-div'

));
echo $form->end();
```

In your controller....

```
function add_data() {
  // ... do something
  $this->layout = 'ajax';
  $this->set('message', 'Your message here!');
}
```

In the add_data view....

```
<?php echo $message; ?>
```

Comment: Hi Patrick, thanks for the detailed code. I'm trying `echo $this->Ajax->link('+', array('action' => 'add_data', $reference_id))`, but nothing happens when I click the button. The displayed URL is correct for the controller action, but data is not inserted. This HTML is created: `<a id="link1260710640" onclick=" event.returnValue = false; return false;" href="/my_app/controller/add_data/1234"></a>`.

Comment: Did you setup the Scriptaculous and Prototype javascript libraries as specified in the cake documentation (http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Helpers/AJAX.html) ?

Comment: Does the data get inserted when you use the regular HTML link you posted in your question?

Comment: ^No, and yes. But I included those two libraries, and it seems to work! I originally had success/fail flash messages with the HTML method. Is it possible to achieve this with the Ajax call as well? With the HTML method, I simply checked the insertion result to decide on success/fail message.

Comment: Yes.  The "update" key in the options array allows you to specify the id of an HTML element on the page.  The content of that element will be replaced with the output of the action.  You'll want to specify $this->layout = 'ajax' inside the add_data action so the entire layout of your site isn't rendered and returned.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure how to get this working. The flash is triggered in the controller. How can the View know how to trigger the flash?

Comment: You'll want the controller action to use the ajax layout and render a view that contains the message.  Then, you can use the "update" key to specify the id of the div where you want the message to display.

Comment: I just updated the answer to include the add_data action and view.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for the View::render method.

```
<?php

...
function addData(...) {
    ...
    ...

    $this->render('search'); // Render the search view instead of the "add_data" view.
}
...

?>
```

or maybe

```
<?php

...
function search(...) {
    ...
    ...

    if (<criteria)
        $this->addData(...); // Move to another action while keeping the current view in tact.
}
...
function addData(...) {
    if (<criteriaForSearchView>)
        $this->render('search');
    // Else render the "add_data" view.
}
...

?>
```

Let me know if this helps! Thanks!